# FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink() is always null

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink() Is always null in iOS when booting the app in release mode.

When the app is closed completely on iOS and the dynamic link is clicked, the app will open but not to the page expected. If the app was running in the background then FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen is triggered and the page redirect can be handled.

I've seen several other bug reports with the same issue from years ago. None really give an answer and all essentially say this is fixed, but for me it's not.

Below initDynamicLink is called from initState in the homePage view (main view of the app)

```
void initDynamicLink() async {
    // WORKS
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen(
      (pendingLink) {
        final Uri deepLink = pendingLink.link;
        Sentry.captureMessage("listen deepLink: $deepLink");
        ref.read(goRouterProvider).push(deepLink.path);
      },
    );

    // DOES NOT WORK
    final linkData = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri? deepLink = linkData?.link;
    if (deepLink != null) {
      ref.read(goRouterProvider).push(deepLink.path);
    }

    Sentry.captureMessage("cold deepLink: $deepLink");
 }
```

I'm running in release mode on the physical device, Sentry will capture the onLink when the app was already running in the background, but for getInitialLink the deepLink is always null

Also the onLink.listen is never triggered if the link was clicked when the app was closed.